# Spark taking long time to return the count of an RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have dataframe that was executed on a query. Data size might be more than 1GB.

After using spark sql, consider I have a dataframe df. After this,

I filtered the dataset into 2 dataframes, 
one with values less than 540 ie filteredFeaturesBefore, another with value between 540 and 640 ie filteredFeaturesAfter

After this, I combined the 2 dataframes mentioned above ie combinedFeatures by using inner join

```
val combinedFeatures = sqlContext.sql("""select * from filteredFeaturesBefore inner join filteredFeaturesAfter on  filteredFeaturesBefore.ID = filteredFeaturesAfter.ID """)
```

Later I create a dataset of LabeledPoint to pass the data into the machine learning model.

```
val combinedRddFeatures = combinedFeatures.rdd

combinedRddFeatures.map(event => LabeledPoint(parseDouble(event(0) + ""), Vectors.dense(parseDouble(event(1) + ""),
        parseDouble(event(2) + ""), parseDouble(event(3) + ""), parseDouble(event(4) + ""))))
```

If I perform, finalSamples.count() spark is executing and is not returning anything for a long time. I executed the program for 6 hours and still no results was returned from spark. I had to stop the execution because laptop was almost slow and was not responding properly.

I dont know whether this is because of my laptop processor speed or is spark hung.

I'm using macBook air 2017 which has a processor of 1.8Ghz.

Can you tell me why is this happening as I'm new to spark.

Also, is there any workaround for this. Instead of splitting the data into 2 dataframes, can I iterate both the dataframes and extract the labelelPoints data structure? If yes, can you suggest me the method to do this.

Comment: So I assume `finalSamples`-RDD is the result of your map over combinedRddFeatures?
Without the exact amount of data you're processing, it' hard to guess where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Also don't forget laziness of spark. The count forces spark to execute every previous step.

Comment: the data might be around 2GB, but I'm not sure because if I join the tables, I cannot know how many rows are present. Hence Once I create a RDD[LabelledPoint] data structure, and then if I try to save the data into libsvm format, it takes around 27GB of data in the local hard disk where I end the program as my local hard disk space exceeded. I dont know how is this possible even?

Comment: Also is there a way I can iterate 2 dataframes are once so that I could avoid the join in scala?

Comment: the way i approach exactly this kind of issue is divide and conquer. @fr3dch3n is absolutely correct about spark being lazy and that often masks the exact point things get slow. so split up the spark code into steps: do the `select` and do a `combinedFeatures.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("some/file.pq")`. then _read back_ the parquet file and get the `rdd`. and so on.